# kernel source 3.10.0-229.11.1.el7.x86_64 compilation fails

Tags: c, gcc, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I updated my gcc from 4.8 to 5.2. After updating gcc I am trying to compile kernel with newer gcc. I am getting a compilation issue

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-229.11.1.el7.x86_64/arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by `arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h'.  Stop.
make: *** [archheaders] Error 2
```

Even after googling several hours. I could not find solution to this problem. Please help!

Comment: Try with a newer kernel from http://kernel.org/

Comment: `syscall_32.tbl` is part of kernel source. Just copy it from a clean source tree.

Answer (score 1):

That target file is part of the source code. Maybe you or someone else deleted it accidentally?